# ac-php "Wrong type argument: hash-table-p, nil" when calling company-complete

Tags: debugging, company-mode, php-mode, company

I'm using emacs 27 compiled from git sources and `company` for code completion.
I tried to set-up [ac-php](https://github.com/xcwen/ac-php) with company and php-mode, but when company tries tp perform auto-complete, I get the following error :

```
Company: An error occurred in auto-begin
Company: backend (company-ac-php-backend company-dabbrev-code) error "Wrong type argument: hash-table-p, nil" with args (candidates $this->)
```

Here is my conf for `php-mode` (the same as advised on ac-php Github):

```
(use-package php-mode
    :ensure t
    :init

    (require 'company-php)
    (add-to-list 'semantic-symref-filepattern-alist  '(php-mode "*.php" "*.tpl"))

    ;; Enable ElDoc support (optional)
    (ac-php-core-eldoc-setup)

    (set (make-local-variable 'company-backends)
      '((company-ac-php-backend company-dabbrev-code)
         company-capf company-files))

     ;; Jump to definition (optional)
     (define-key php-mode-map (kbd "M-]")
      'ac-php-find-symbol-at-point)

     ;; Return back (optional)
     (define-key php-mode-map (kbd "M-[")
      'ac-php-location-stack-back)
   )
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Unless someone has a quick and helpful answer, maybe set `debug-on-error` to `t`, to get a backtrace, and show that.

Comment: You should put your php setup to php-mode-hook using `add-hook`, as the README suggests, since the php backend in `company-backends` only makes sense inside a php file.

Comment: Thanks, it worked =)